# Left Outer Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have out of idea how to do a solution to my problem using the LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server

I have a scenario like this:

**Scenario for Roles**

```
--------------------
    User Access
--------------------
UserID  |  RoleID
--------------------
1-123   |  1
1-123   |  2
1-456   |  1
1-456   |  3
---------------------


--------------------
      Profile
--------------------
UserID  |  Name
--------------------
1-123   |  John
1-456   |  Carl
---------------------

--------------------
     User Role
--------------------
Role ID |  Role Name
--------------------
1       |  Teacher
2       |  Employee
3       |  Head
4       |  IT Staff
---------------------
```

Here is my problem

I want to show all roles that `UserID : 1-123` not assigned (Note: assignment of roles is in User Access).

I tried `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to view which not present to the other table but it only showed IT Staff which both users dont have.

Please Help Me

Comment: which query did you try ? Show it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways.  Here's one approach using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserRole
WHERE RoleId NOT IN (
    SELECT RoleId
    FROM UserAccess
    WHERE UserId = '1-123')
```

This will return all roles that user '1-123' does not have.

---

Here's how to do it with an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserRole U
   LEFT JOIN UserAccess UA ON U.RoleId = UA.RoleID AND UA.UserId = '1-123'
WHERE UA.UserId IS NULL
```

---

And here's an approach using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserRole UR
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM UserAccess UA
    WHERE UserId = '1-123' AND UA.RoleId = UR.RoleId)
```

Comment: Thank a lot for this answer..what a nice approach..very useful Thank a lot u save my day of searching this one